# How to set braces in the same line in Qt creator

Tags: qt-creator

I'm new to Qt and I want to change to braces coding style in Qt creator on Mac OS from

```
void foo() 
{
    ....
}
```

To

```
void foo() {
}
```

Comment: Normally, I press Enter only after space, open-bracket to execute your second behaviour. I'm... not sure this is something you could configure? Unless you're trying to reformat pre-existing code...

Answer (score 0):

see https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-beautifier.html
In short, you have to install beautifier plugin. Each available plugin has it's own settings.